# Script stops reading text file at line 2689, but file is much longer

Tags: python, file

I am reading a text file line by line, checking for duplicates, but the script stops well less then half way through the file, at line 2689.

```
import sys


doc = "people.txt"
lst = []
line_num = 0
with open(doc) as f:
    with open(f"{doc}.cleaned", "w") as w:
        for line in f:
            if line not in lst:
                lst.append(line)
                w.write(line)
            line_num = line_num + 1
            print (line_num)
```

Am I running up against a maximum length of a list?
An iterator?
Something else?

Comment: Is there any error that the script shows? How large is the file that you are reading?

Comment: Your duplicate checking would be *vastly* more efficient if you used a set rather than a list to hold the seen lines.

Comment: Python lists can hold up to the max value of a 32 bit integer elements, so that is definitely not your problem

Comment: Have you tried to check how many lines have 'people.txt' ? On linux you can do `wc -l people.txt`

Comment: Are you sure the script has stopped as opposed to merely getting really slow? Note that the `line not in lst` check can become very slow — it's a linear search — if the list is long (and more so if the strings in it are, too).

Comment: As martineau says, for example 6,000 lines * 3,000 items in lst is 18,000,000 comparisons.

Comment: there are 12928 lines. The script, run from shell in Linux, outputs no errors. I added the print line to see progress.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be slow, its quite fast, just stops at 2689

Comment: What's the content of line 2689?